# R - Read excel file with each line between quotes, comma separator, and variables between quotes with comma

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I would like to read an excel file with each line between quotes, comma separator, and variables between quotes with commas but the column names are not between quotes... Here is an example of my csv file :

> variable 1, variable 2, variable 3 
> "3, "2,1", "1,2"" 
> "2, "3,2", "2,3"" 
> "1, "4,3", "3,4""

[the same example in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9brI.jpg)

I did not succeed to read the file correctly with read.csv, read_csv, read.table... I thought of reading the file as a list, extracting each line, transforming the commas between quotes by points and then reading the list as a csv but I think there are easier ways.

What do you think about it ?

Thank you very much,

Have a nice day,

Lilou

Comment: Can you provide an example of a line in the `.csv` file?

Comment: Thank you, I just added an example in the post.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use `readr::read_table` to import the data with spaces as separators, then remove the unwanted commas and quotes that are left behind:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

#Import as space separated file, skipping column names:
read_table('variable 1, variable 2, variable 3
            "3, "2,1", "1,2""
            "2, "3,2", "2,3""
            "1, "4,3", "3,4""', skip = 1, col_names = FALSE)  %>% 
#Remove non-numeric and non-comma characters, and remove trailing commas:
  mutate(across(1:3, ~ gsub('([^0-9,])|(,$)', '', .x)))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  X1    X2    X3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 3     2,1   1,2  
2 2     3,2   2,3  
3 1     4,3   3,4
```

How appropriate this is for your case will depend on how well behaved the data you want to import are, but hopefully this can be of some use.